# Why isn't \n\n breaking lines when saving text to file?

Tags: php, file

I have this function which writes content to a text file:

```
function write($text){
  fwrite($this->fp, '#' . date('H:i d.m.Y') . ': ' . $text . "\n\n");
}
```

Each time this is called, text is added and new line is invoked.

But if I have do something like this:

```
$text = 'some text \n\n Some more text.';
write($text)
```

Then the line break in the text is not "working".

Why is that? What am I missing?

Here is the entire function I'm using to record debugging data:

```
  class logDebuggData {
    private $fp = NULL;

    function __construct($name='log', $dir=''){
      $this->fp = fopen(TEMPLATE_DIR.$name.'.txt', 'a+');
    }

    function write($text){
      fwrite($this->fp, '#' . date('H:i d.m.Y') . ': ' . $text . "\n\n");
    }

    function close(){
      if ($this->fp) {
        fclose($this->fp);
        $this->fp = NULL;
      }
    }

    function __destruct() {
      $this->close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read (and this applies to *everyone* who lands on this page, not just the OP) [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Properly. Read your manuals. Know them. Love them. They are your friends.

Comment: You should also use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` or `\r\n` as `PHP_EOL` will determine which one to use based on which platform its on.

Comment: +1 @LawrenceCherone - with caveat that if you're implementing something defined by someone else, use the line ending style they define. The most notable violation I see with that on a regular basis is people constructing MIME messages using `PHP_EOL`, when they should be using an explicit `\r\n`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use double quotes and not single quotes:

```
$text = "some text \n\n Some more text.";
        ^                              ^
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was any difference.